# glmmadmb no longer supported in lsmeans. Alternative packages?

Tags: lsmeans, pscl

My data is zero inflated so I'm running a zero-inflated model using glmmamdb:

**Model3z <- glmmadmb(Count3 ~ Light3 + (1|Site3), zeroInflation = T, family= "poisson", data = dframe3)**

However, when I try and do pairwise comparisons of the different light types in this model **pwcs3 <- lsmeans(Model3z, "Light")** I get the error message:

Error in ref_grid(object, ...) : 
  Can't handle an object of class  “glmmadmb” 
 Use help("models", package = "emmeans") for information on supported models.

When I go on the emmeans package website it says that glmmadmb is no longer supported.

I've switched to pscl and the zeroinfl function but am unsure on how to restructure my code to fit the pscl format. Typing in **P <- zeroinfl(Count3 ~ Light3 + (1|Site3), family = poisson, data = dframe3)** gets the error message:

Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(1, Site3) : ‘|’ not meaningful for factors

Is there another way of using glmmadmb with lsmeans? If not, does anyone know how a zero-inflated model code in pscl is supposed to look? Thanks.

Comment: Isn’t glmmTMB similar? That package is supported by emmeans.

Comment: You could also try the `qdrg()` function. See its help page.

Comment: I've switched to glmmTMB: 

Model3z <- glmmTMB(Count3 ~ Light3 + (1|Site3), ziformula = ~ 1, family= "poisson", data = dframe3)

But now whenever I type pwcs3 <- lsmeans(Model3z, "Light") I get the error message 'No variable named Light in the reference grid'

Comment: Well, it looks like the variable in the model is named Light3, not Light

Comment: Thank you! Everything's working now. Can't believe I missed something that simple.